# node sass watch doesnt work when called from subscript

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

Sorry if the title isn't very explicit.

So I have those scripts in my package.json in a React App build from create-react-app.

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
```

This works well as changes in scss files are correctly watched after a **`yarn watch-css`**

But when I want to simplify the **`watch-css`** script like that :

```
"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && npm run build-css --watch --recursive",
```

But the watch functionality this doesn't work anymore.

So, is there any way to avoid to duplicate the **`build-css`** script ??

Thanks.